# SP19: Item Reminder

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, 2019

In SharePoint 2013 a custom SharePoint Designer workflow could be created to create a reminder email to be triggered on line items.  In SharePoint 2019 how would I create a reminder email to be triggered on line items?  Would it keep the same as I would of done it in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing for sharepoint 2013 and 2019. 
You will use SharePoint 2010 workflow or with workflow manager (SharePoint 2013 workflow) using SharePoint designer 2013.